# Regular Expression for Alphanumeric characters with one special char in between

Tags: c#, regex

can anyone please help me to figure `Regex` attribute for string field. 
I want my string should be in format of `FirstName@LastName` thats is it.. I require only one special char in between and rest all alphabets only..

Comment: Do note that some names have dashes, periods, apostrophes, and spaces.

Comment: Yeah, nut not in my case.

Comment: what other characters are acceptable in place of `@`?

Comment: only @... Does that make diff?? just curious

Answer (score 3):

You can use the expression `[A-Za-z]+@[A-Za-z]+` to test against a nonempty string of alphabetical characters, followed by an `@` sign and again followed by a nonempty string of alphabetical characters. You can test it online [here](https://regex101.com/).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to accept any non-alphanumeric characters in the middle, like `$,@,_,-` etc, you can use the following,

```
[a-zA-Z]+[^a-zA-Z\d\s][a-zA-Z]+
```

it will match all these among others,

```
FirstName@LastName
FirstName-LastName
FirstName_LastName
FirstName$LastName
FirstName:LastName
```

[Live Demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5Ba-zA-Z%5D%2B%5B%5Ea-zA-Z%5Cd%5Cs%5D%5Ba-zA-Z%5D%2B&i=%20%20%20%20FirstName%40LastName%0D%0A%20%20%20%20FirstName-LastName%0D%0A%20%20%20%20FirstName_LastName%0D%0A%20%20%20%20FirstName%24LastName%0D%0A%20%20%20%20FirstName%3ALastName)

If you want to match `whitespace` in between as well then simply remove `\s` from above expression.

Hope it helps.